# Vue 3 migration. Prop types became unknown

Tags: typescript, vue.js, migration, eslint

I have been migrating the application from Vue 2 to Vue 3 following: https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-3-migration-build/. I ran into the issue related to Props and their types. Seems like all the props got type unknown according to "linter". Because it does not show any errors on the template itself.

For example.
I have the prop "cancelText" which is defined like this:

```
cancelText: {
            type: String as PropType<string>,
            default: "",
        },
```

And then I use this prop inside computed property like this:

```
cancelButtonText(): string {
            return this.cancelText || this.$t("PRODUCT.ACTION_BAR.BACK");
        },
```

When I hover on the variable it displays the type, so it seems like it understand what type it is: [image]

But when serving the application, I am getting this error inside the terminal

```
TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[image]

Either some package is not compatible, or some linting rules needs to be updated specifically for Vue 3.

Here is the dependencies I am using:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
    "@sentry/browser": "^6.6.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^6.6.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.6.0",
    "@vue/compat": "3.2.36",
    "ant-design-vue": "^2.2.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.8.1",
    "vue-flag-icon": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.15",
    "vue3-touch-events": "^4.1.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.15.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.36",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-playwright": "^0.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "less": "^3.13.0",
    "less-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
},
```

And here eslint rules:

```
module.exports = {
env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
    node: true,
},
extends: [
    "plugin:playwright/playwright-test",
    "plugin:vue/base",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
],
parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
    parser: {
        // Script parser for `<script>`
        js: false,

        // Script parser for `<script lang="ts">`
        ts: "@typescript-eslint/parser",

        // Script parser for vue directives (e.g. `v-if=` or `:attribute=`) and vue interpolations (e.g. `{{variable}}`).
        // If not specified, the parser determined by `<script lang ="...">` is used.
        "<template>": false,
    },
},
plugins: ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
rules: {
    // Custom rules added by us
    "no-else-return": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
    "no-console": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
        "warn",
        {
            vars: "all",
            args: "after-used",
            ignoreRestSiblings: false,
            argsIgnorePattern: "^_",
            varsIgnorePattern: "^_",
            caughtErrorsIgnorePattern: "^_",
        },
    ],
    "vue/no-unused-properties": [
        "warn",
        {
            groups: ["props", "data", "computed", "methods", "setup"],
            deepData: true,
            ignorePublicMembers: true,
        },
    ],
    "vue/html-self-closing": [
        "warn",
        {
            html: {
                void: "always",
            },
            svg: "always",
            math: "always",
        },
    ],
    "vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline": "off",
    "vue/html-closing-bracket-newline": "off",
    "vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline": "off",
    //end of custom rules added by us
    "vue/html-indent": "off",
    "vue/max-attributes-per-line": "off",
    "vue/this-in-template": ["error", "never"],
    "vue/attributes-order": [
        "error",
        {
            order: [
                "DEFINITION",
                "LIST_RENDERING",
                "CONDITIONALS",
                "RENDER_MODIFIERS",
                "GLOBAL",
                "UNIQUE",
                "TWO_WAY_BINDING",
                "OTHER_DIRECTIVES",
                "OTHER_ATTR",
                "EVENTS",
                "CONTENT",
            ],
            alphabetical: false,
        },
    ],
    "vue/order-in-components": [
        "error",
        {
            order: [
                "el",
                "name",
                "parent",
                "functional",
                ["delimiters", "comments"],
                ["components", "directives", "filters"],
                "extends",
                "mixins",
                "inheritAttrs",
                "model",
                ["props", "propsData"],
                "data",
                "computed",
                "watch",
                "LIFECYCLE_HOOKS",
                "methods",
                ["template", "render"],
                "renderError",
            ],
        },
    ],
},
overrides: [
    {
        files: ["**/*.ts"],
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
        parserOptions: {
            tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
            project: "tsconfig.json",
        },
        extends: [
            "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
            // This enables stricter type checking for ts
            // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        ],
        rules: {
            "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["warn", { ignoreRestArgs: false }],
        },
    },
    {
        files: ["**/tests/*.{j,t}s?(x)", "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"],
        env: {
            jest: true,
        },
    },
],};
```

Comment: Why does the question mention linter? This problem seems to occur in TS compiler. FWIW, TS support in options API was inferior by design. Probably it went broken at some point. Composition API is preferable in Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.$t("<key>") as string
```

If you are migrating to vue 3, use composition/vue because many plugins have officially stopped supporting legacy APIs such as `this.$t` such as vue-auth3, vue-i18n

Answer (score 0):

remove plugin 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin'

for webpack chain

use:

```js
config.plugins.delete('fork-ts-checker').end()
```